# parametrizing the number of line displayed in a grid using EXTJS

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

Is there any way to `parametrize`the number of line displayed in a grid using `EXTJS`?
For exemple having a `combobox`which can tell me how many lines I want to display : if I choose 10, the grid will display 10 lines ...etc

Comment: You mean no. of records in grid.Right?

Comment: no, not the number of records, what i mean is like in this example : https://datatables.net the combobox Show.

Answer (score 0):

> You can add combo to your top docked toolbar :

```
{
  xtype     :'combo',
  fieldLabel    :'Show',
  labelSeparator:'',
  name      :'show',
  labelWidth    :30,
  value     :'10',
  store     :[10,20,50],
  listeners :{
      change:function( thisObj, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ){
          pageSize = newValue;
          store = Ext.getStore('gridStore');
          store.pageSize = pageSize;
          Ext.getCmp('pagingToolbarID').moveFirst();
      }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :-)